# Is there a good alternative to what the word "equivocate" seems to mean?

Tags: single-word-requests, equivalence

I thought "equivocate" means to make two concepts seem the same, or to compare them. Turns out "equivocate" just means "use ambiguous language so as to conceal the truth or avoid committing oneself." But it turns out I'm not the only that was confused:

From https://www.cjr.org/language_corner/equivocate-equivalence.php

> Stop misusing the word ‘equivocate’

> “Trump’s statements last week are provided as just one of the latest examples of this false equivalency that is corrupting the political dialogue of our political system. It might be a risk of committing false equivocation ourselves to say ideologues on both the right and left commit these disingenuous arguments, but there are enough examples that we feel safe to call it a fact.”

> “The Republican president’s statements have been widely criticized as equivocating between white nationalists, including Ku Klux Klan members and neo-Nazis, on the one hand and those protesting against them on the other.”

Is there a word that actually means comparing with intent to present as equal? I think the best option I found was "equate".

Comment: You could see if *conflate* does what you want.

Comment: I think _analogize_ might work.

Comment: Compare itself carries this sense: << **compare verb** [T] (consider similarities)
 
to judge, suggest, or consider that something is similar **or of equal quality** [bolding mine]  to something else:
... ⁕ Still only 25, she has been compared to the greatest dancer of all time. / ⁕ People compared her to Elizabeth Taylor.
.... >> [[CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compare)] Hence 'incomparable'.  I don't think this constitutes a valid 'answer' as no research is **shown**.

Comment: Use two words: "falsely equate"—same number of syllables as "equivocate" so your mouth won't get much tireder from saying the phrase instead of the single word.

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence. This is a requirement for this type of question. And while editing your question I would remove all reference to your previous misunderstanding of equivocate. It is irrelevant as is the ignorance of anyone else on this point.

Comment: Hi David, why should I edit out my ignorance in the question? Which part exactly do you want me to remove? The whole point of a question is to deignorantificate, no? Also - there are example sentences in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already listed the answer: [equate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equate)

> 2 : to treat, represent, or regard as equal, equivalent, or comparable (*equates disagreement with disloyalty*)

Though, there is a less formal vernacular backformation (and possibly influenced by the form of *[equivocate](https://www.txstate.edu/philosophy/resources/fallacy-definitions/Equivocation.html)*) which has given rise to *[equivalate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/equivalate)* but this is [less commonly used than *equate* by a great degree](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equivalate%2C%20equate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cequivalate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cequate%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cequivalate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cequate%3B%2Cc0).